# Sending a list of files through a socket

Tags: python, list, file, sockets, server

At school we were asked to write something like that on the server side:

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob(r'C:\FolderName\*.*)
```

And then to send file_list (I hope it is possible, anyways that's what I understand from the question) to the client side through a socket. How can it be done?

Comment: Start by working through this how-to: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sockets.html If you run into problems doing the implementation and have a specific question, then we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you :) I have to convert the list into bytes in order to send it, right? How do I do that?

Comment: For that, in descending order of sophistication, you could use `pickle`, or `json`, or a long string delimited by carriage returns: `'\n'.join(file_list)`.

Comment: Thank you :) ---